# What does the term "fremdschämen" mean? How to write it correctly?

Tags: german-to-english, neologism

Saw [this](http://superslang.de/suche?anfrage=fremd%20sch%C3%A4men&x=3&y=6) in a chat, doesn't yield an answer.

Is this similar to have a pity on somebody?
And how to write those word-creations? Is there a general rule of thumb?

Seems pretty arbitrary. I saw:

- fremd schämen
- fremd-schämen
- fremdschämen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chats are not representative for how to write words, of course, neither in German, nor in English or French. Like most other composite words, this is written in one word. Duden has [an entry on it](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fremdschaemen), with the meaning:

> sich stellvertretend für andere, für deren als peinlich empfundenes Auftreten schämen

In English: If someone does something which makes you feel embarrassed for him, you can say (example from Duden):

> ich konnte mir seine Darbietung nicht ansehen, ohne mich fremdzuschämen

dict.cc lists "to feel embarrassed for sb. else" as a translation for fremdschämen.

Comment: You can also simply say the one word sentence _Fremdschämen!_ At least that's how I mostly use it.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Never heard it that way. When exactly do you say it, and to whom (to the embarrassing person, or to other *Fremdschämende*?) :)

Comment: ‍@OregonGhost: to other _Fremdschämende_. In particular when watching embarrising stuff on TV.

Answer (score -2):

Das Wort ist überflüssiger Mumpitz, weil Scham immer nur im Zusammenhang mit einem oder mehreren anderen auftritt, und deren Fremdheit nichts zur Sache tut - dieser Wortbestandteil trifft also gar nicht, was er treffen will.

Situationen, in denen erst der Begriff eine Zweideutigkeit klärt, kann ich mir auch nicht denken, aber vielleicht kann mich ja ein Beispiel überzeugen.

Ich schäme mich für den Duden, der das Wort unnötigerweise aufgenommen hat.

(Neue Sprechung, nur zu Demonstrationszwecken - ich rate dringend ab:

> Ich schäme mich für den Duden, der das Wort unnötigerweise
>   aufgenommen hat, fremd.

Grässlich wie wenig in der dt. Sprache.

Comment: [Sprache lebt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvz0cNoUlaY)

Comment: Eine Wertung ist keine Antwort. :)

Comment: Abgesehen von der Wertung: Der Unterschied zwischen schämen und fremdschämen ist der, daß beim Fremdschämen eine Handlung oder Eigenschaft des anderen die Scham auslöst, nicht wie beim "normalen" schämen, die eigene.

Comment: @Burki: Die Unterstellung, dass man beim Schämen sich für sich selbst schämt, ist aus der Luft gegriffen und falsch. Dass man sich für andere schämt ist keineswegs neu, nur das dringende Bedürfnis dafür einen anderen Begriff zu benutzen ist eine moderne Manier.